# ArcGIS Javascript API Printing issue

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I am trying to print the ArcGIS JS API Web Map in Large prints (ANSI D, ANSI E) by using as per below code:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_print_esri_request.html

The issue what I am facing is the print out which is on the map are shrinking on large pints outs, but coming properly in small prints (A4 and A3).

I tried below options, but no proper results are coming.

```
1.printTemplate.exportOptions = { width: map.width, height: map.height,                        dpi: 96 };
2.printTemplate.preserveScale = false;
```

Comment: Can you show all of the printTemplate's properties.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be requesting map image of higher resolution than can be exported from an ArcGIS service by default, for example (https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/PoolPermits/MapServer): 
MaxImageHeight: 4096
MaxImageWidth: 4096

For ANSI E the longer side is 44'', which, at 96 dpi, corresponds to 4224 dots. I am not sure why ANSI D is not exporting properly, but, as Suttikeat Witchayakul suggested, providing the rest of printing parameters as well as the service(s) URL(s), which you are trying to export map from, may help.

The maximum image size that can be exported from a service can be specified at time the service is published. Alternatively, a lower resolution map image can be requested to prevent unexpected shrinking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize or create new print template located at
..\ArcGIS\Server\Templates\ExportWebMapTemplates\ folder and restart print service.
now your new template will be added to the dropdown list of print templates.